# Ajuda com busca de informações em um html com js/node

Tags: javascript, algoritmo-de-busca

eu estou com dificuldade na implementação de um código. Já fui ajudado em outro momento e agora estou precisando novamente.
O objetivo é um script que me ajude a retirar de um html o nome dos professores e o link de seus respectivos lattes, salvar de alguma forma para posteriormente eu tratar os dados.
Sou iniciante nesse mundo e ainda não sei trabalhar com jquery, porém nada impede de eu utilizar essa opção caso eu seja orientado.
Analisando o código html da página, pude reparar que a tag html `<h2>` é unicamente utilizada para os nomes dos professores, então eu peguei o conteudo de todas as headers2 e consegui salvar. Percebi que após essa tag, o próximo "href" é onde se encontra o link lattes do respectivo professor... Estou preso exatamente nesse ponto. 
Falei bastante mas acho que consegui ser claro.
Obrigado galera.

```
    const url = 'http://www.ppg-educacao.uff.br/novo/index.php/corpo-docente'
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')


axios.get(url).then(response =>{
    const funcionarios = response.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
    const professores = $('h2').text()
    console.log($('h2').text())
    //const lattes = $('a href="http://lattes.cnpq.br/"' ).text()
    //console.log(lattes)
    //const informacoes = []
    //informacoes.push({'nome ': professores, 'lattes ': lattes})
    //console.log (informacoes)

})
```

[image: Saída atual com os nomes dos professores.]

Answer (score 0):

Analisando a DOM da página percebe-se que cada professor está em um bloco `<div>` com seus elementos padronizados (o que facilita nossa leitura dos dados), com a classe *item column-1*.

O único elemento `h2` é o nome do professor, como você fez.
O segundo elemento `p` contém um único elemento `a` que é o link para o currículo.

Para selecionarmos as divs com jQuery, utilizamos `$('.item.column-1')`

O código ficaria assim, resultando em uma array de objetos com nome e link.

```
var professores = []
$('.item.column-1').each(function(index) {
  var nome = $(this).children('h2').text()
  var link = $(this).find('p a')[0].href
  professores.push({
    nome: nome,
    link: link
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifiquei o código pra você.

```
const url = 'http://www.ppg-educacao.uff.br/novo/index.php/corpo-docente'
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

let objs = []
let nomes = []
let urls = []

axios.get(url).then(response =>{
    const funcionarios = response.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
    $('h2').each((i, e) => {
        nomes.push(e.children[0].data.trim());
    });
    $('p a').each((i, e) => {
        urls.push(e.attribs.href);
    });

    nomes.forEach((nome,i) => {
        objs.push({nome: nomes[i], lattes: urls[i]});
    });

    console.log(objs);
})
```

**Resultado:**

```
[ { nome: 'Adriano Vargas Freitas',
    lattes: 'http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4276752U6' },
  { nome: 'Alessandra Frota Schueler',
    lattes: 'http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4799322D6' },
  { nome: 'Bruno Alves Dassie',
    lattes: 'http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4707912H5' },
  { nome: 'Carlos Eduardo Zaleski Rebuá',
    lattes: 'http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4260783J4' },
  { nome: 'Carmen Lúcia Vidal Pérez',
    lattes: 'http://lattes.cnpq.br/0646181238100482' },
  { nome: 'Cecilia Maria Aldigueri Goulart',
    lattes: 'http://lattes.cnpq.br/7281306371405447' },

    ...
{ nome: 'Valdelúcia Alves da Costa',
    lattes: 'http://lattes.cnpq.br/3766561922402070' },
  { nome: 'Waldeck Carneiro',
    lattes: 'http://lattes.cnpq.br/4129978776761994' },
  { nome: 'Zoia Ribeiro Prestes',
    lattes: 'http://lattes.cnpq.br/1927800358488148' },
  { nome: 'Zuleide Simas da Silveira',
    lattes: 'http://lattes.cnpq.br/8037763146233564' } ]
```